# Reading irregular colunm data into python 3.X using pandas or numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Below is my piece of code.

```
import numpy as np

filename1=open(f)
xf = np.loadtxt(filename1, dtype=float)
```

Below is my data file.

```
0.14200E+02 0.18188E+01 0.44604E-03
0.14300E+02 0.18165E+01 0.45498E-03
0.14400E+02-0.17694E+01 0.44615E+03
0.14500E+02-0.17226E+01 0.43743E+03
0.14600E+02-0.16767E+01 0.42882E+03
0.14700E+02-0.16318E+01 0.42033E+03
0.14800E+02-0.15879E+01 0.41196E+03
```

as one can see there are negative values that take up the space between 2 values this causes numpy to give

```
ValueError: Wrong number of columns at line 3
```

This is just small snippet of my code. I want to read this data using numpy or pandas. Any suggestion would be great.

Edit 1:

@ZarakiKenpachi I used your suggestion of sep=' |-' but it gives me extra 4th column with NaN values.

Edit 2:

@Serge Ballesta nice suggestion but all these are some kind of pre-processing. I want some kind of inbuild function to do this in pandas or numpy.

Edit 3:

**Important Note** it should be noted that there also negative sign in 0.4373E-03

Thank-you

Comment: what is input file format and how the data is formatted inside?

Comment: I have provided the data in the question it is .dat file with space separated.

Comment: the column with negative numbers is properly separated inside the file? If so then use pd.read_csv(data.dat, sep=' |-', engine='python')

Comment: In the question I have mentioned that the space is taken by the negative sign in the data.

Comment: yep but in file too?

Comment: the data provided is from the file. you just have to copy the data to text file and save as .dat file. there is no space between the 2 columns the negative sign takes up the spaces 0.14500E+02-0.17226E+01 0.43743E-03. it should be noted that there also negative sign in 0.4373E-03

Comment: Although the answer might tell you how to fix things after the event, you should really fix whatever generates your data in the first place to use a sane system of column separation.

Comment: @Leporello: The data file is output of the tool I am using. I don't have much control over the output the tool generates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.loadtext` can read from a (byte string) generator, so you can filter the input file while loading it to add an additional before a minus:

```
...
def filter(fd):
    rx = re.compile(rb'\d-')
    for line in fd:
        yield rx.sub(b' -', line)

xf = np.loadtxt(filter(open(f, 'b')), dtype=float)
```

This does not require to preload everything into memory, so it is expected to be memory efficient.

---

The regex is required to avoid to change something like `0.16545E-012`.

In my tests for 10k lines, this should be at most 10% slower than loading everything in memory but will require far less memory

Comment: I have some 23 files each having 10K lines will this have some performance issues.

Comment: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0.16545E'

Comment: @RohitModee: My code did not accept negative exponents. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a preprocess your data to add an additional space before your `-` signs. While there are many ways of doing it, the best approach would be in my opinion (in order to avoid adding whitespaces at the start of the line) is using regex re.sub:

```
import re

with open(f) as file:
    raw_data = file.readlines()

processed_data = re.sub(r'(?:\d)-', " -", raw_data)

xf = np.loadtxt(processed_data, dtype=float)
```

This replaces every `-` preceded by a number with `-`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code :

```
with open('app.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()

import re 
data_mod = []
for number in data.split('\n')[:-1]:
    num = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+-[\w\.-]',number)
    for n in num:
        number = number.replace('-',' -')
    data_mod.append(number)

with open('mod_text.txt','w') as f:
    for data in data_mod:
        f.write(data+"\n")

filename1='mod_text.txt'
xf = np.loadtxt(filename1, dtype=float)
```

Actually you have to per-process the data, using regex. After that you can load that data as you required.

I hope this helps.